# Macro for template definitions

Tags: c++, templates, macros, alias

I have a problem with alias template, because I have a code which must be compatible with VS 2012, which does not support alias template.

Let's say I have an alias template like:

```
template<typename A, typename B> using foo = bar<A,B>;
```

Then it would be very convenient to be able to do something like:

```
#ifdef NO_ALIAS_TEMPLATE_AVAILABLE
    #define foo<x,y> bar<x,y>
#else
    template<typename A, typename B> using foo = bar<A,B>;
#endif
```

However the best I can do is

```
    #define foo(x,y) bar<x,y>
```

And I don't want to replace all template specializations in all my code by round brackets, for code readability.

Is there any way to have a macro with delimiters `<>` for its argument? Or is there no simple solution to my problem? If not, how to implement a strict equivalence to alias template?

Answer (score 2):

No, the preprocessor cannot use `<>` to delimit macro arguments.

You can emulate an alias template with a class template:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct foo {
    typedef bar<A, B> type;
};

// Usage: foo<A, B>::type
// Generic context: typename foo<A, B>::type
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/SNHNzP)

This would make its usage less nice, but that's unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

The following simpler solution works for me.

```
#ifdef NO_ALIAS_TEMPLATE_AVAILABLE
    #define foo bar
#else
    template<typename A, typename B> using foo = bar<A,B>;
#endif
```

Given

```
template <typename A, typename B> struct bar {};
```

the following lines work fine.

```
foo<int, double> f; // Ok.
bar<int, double> b; // Ok.
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea for common names of `foo`, but it's actually not that bad if you are careful with your macro names: `#define MY_LIBRARY_FOO ::fully::qualified::bar` and `template <typename A, typename B> using MY_LIBRARY_FOO = bar<A, B>`